# How to calculate bank statement debit/credit columns using balance column of pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one dataframe which looks like below:

```
                   Date_1                Date_2         DR      CR      Bal
0                5 Dec 2017               5 Dec 2017    500     NaN     1000
1               14 Dec 2017               14 Dec 2017   NaN     NaN     1500
2               15 Dec 2017               15 Dec 2017   NaN     NaN     1200
3               18 Dec 2017               18 Dec 2017   NaN     NaN     1700
4               21 Dec 2017               21 Dec 2017   NaN     NaN     2000
5               22 Dec 2017                22 Dec 2017  NaN     NaN     1000
```

In the above dataframe "Bal" column contains balance values and want to fill up the DR/CR values based on the next "Bal" amount.

I did it using simple python but seems like pandas can perform this action in very intelligent manner.

Expected Output:

```
                   Date_1                Date_2         DR      CR      Bal
0                5 Dec 2017               5 Dec 2017    500     NaN     1000
1               14 Dec 2017               14 Dec 2017   NaN     500     1500
2               15 Dec 2017               15 Dec 2017   300     NaN     1200
3               18 Dec 2017               18 Dec 2017   NaN     500     1700
4               21 Dec 2017               21 Dec 2017   NaN     300     2000
5               22 Dec 2017                22 Dec 2017  1000    NaN     1000
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a [`pd.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html). First calculate the difference of the balance by using [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html). By using mask, fill one column by its absolute value if it's negative, and mask the `np.nan` values in the other column where it's positive.

```
diff = df['Bal'].diff()
df['DR'] = df['DR'].mask(diff < 0, diff.abs())
df['CR'] = df['CR'].mask(diff > 0, diff)

#Output
#                 Date_1  Date_2      DR     CR   Bal
#0 5  Dec 2017 5     Dec    2017   500.0    NaN  1000
#1 14 Dec 2017 14    Dec    2017     NaN  500.0  1500
#2 15 Dec 2017 15    Dec    2017   300.0    NaN  1200
#3 18 Dec 2017 18    Dec    2017     NaN  500.0  1700
#4 21 Dec 2017 21    Dec    2017     NaN  300.0  2000
#5 22 Dec 2017 22    Dec    2017  1000.0    NaN  1000
```

Comment: @Jondiedoop- Thanks. I need help. suppose I have list of numbers - [500.0, 1000.0, 500.0, 1500.0, 300.0, 1200.0, 500.0, 1700.0, 300.0, 2000.0, 1000.0, 1000.0] then can we calculate same statement from above numbers?

Comment: You could just turn it into a dataframe using `pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=['Bal'])`. Is that what you mean? I'm unsure why we're dealing with lists instead of DataFrames now, as explicitly mentioned in the question

Comment: @Jondiedoop- You didn't get my point. The above list contains all the numbers which are available in CR,DR and Bal columns. we need to analyze and fill the values in the DR, CR and Bal columns.

Comment: You're right, I do not get your point. Are you saying you already have the results and now want to put them in a DataFrame? Because that would be an interesting, but new question, very well suited for a new StackOverflow-question. I suppose my answer would sitll be: take odd element from the list and repeat the above steps, but yeah

Comment: ok. please look at the new question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54341392